# Identifier expected error React TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mapping, react-typescript

I'm trying to use a map but I keep getting this error message an expected identifier which falls under the "." of the 4th line, could anyone provide some insight?

```
list.map((a)=>
   <div>
       <p>{a.[userMessage]}</p>
   </div>)
```

I've looked online for an answer but I cant find anything that relates

Comment: that's not how object key accessing work, you can write `a.userMessage` or `a["userMessage"]`.

Comment: or if it's a computed property, `a[userMessage]`

Comment: @RiadhAdrani additionally `a?.[userMessage]` if that value is not guaranteed to exist.

Comment: problem is with that `.` , if the problem persists, update your question and share the actual error too